# How to put special characters in a link?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, hyperlinks

I am trying to edit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170175/1934286) which contains a link.

```
http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans\
```

However, in the preview and also in the now approved edit, the SE engine changes the `:` to `%3a`. See for yourself.

http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

So the link above doesn't lead to the right place. But if you copy and paste the link with the colons in it it does lead to the right place. It did preserve the colons in the original post, but now even the revision shows the incorrect link with the %3a

Is there a trick here or is this a bug?

## Edit for testing to get SE to reparse the post.

**First, a snapshot of original post to prove that problem did exist at time of posting:**

[image]

**Now a snapshot of what is shown on the edit screen. Notice that the link looks correct in the preview.**

[image]

**Now some markdown with all the various ways to make a link**

```
http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans\
```

http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans\

[Test link.](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

[Test link.](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans%5C)

Comment: It's interesting Google of all sites doesn't handle this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this issue at this time. [This test link](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans) which uses markdown appears to work properly.

Comment: The issue did indeed exist at time of posting. Click edit on my OP. You will see that I just pasted the link in there and it came out wrong after SE processes it. Inspect the element and look at the HTML. SE *did* do this wrong in the past. Also, you just edited it for a retag, and the problem is still there. You did reproduce it when you edited the tags.

Comment: Perhaps my browser is parsing the escaped code(s) correctly? Can you show me some screen grabs of this, perhaps step by step?

Comment: I just made a second answer and it is not doing it in any situation. Maybe I should just try editing the op. That is the only situation that hasn't been tried yet.

Comment: I edited the original and it looks like it has been reparsed correctly. The trailing backslash must be escaping the `)` in the test link. I don't think any of this helps because it is not happening anymore. Oh well.

Comment: Just to be sure, maybe try a rollback to version one. I'll let you decide if you still want to fiddle with this.

Comment: @fredsbend glad it's fixed. I won't do a rollback for now as it should not be a problem going forward. Thanks for supplying detailed information on the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Testing if I can reproduce it as well.

[Test link.](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

Plain link: http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans\

Comment: So that markdown looks correct, but it rendered like that. A different issue maybe. But the plain link looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Second test.

**link in code block first.**

```
http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans
```

**link separately**

http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

**link inline markdown**

[Test link](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

**link using link button in editor**

[Test link](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

**Original markdown of this post (excluding this code block).**

```
Second test.

**link in code block first.**

    http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

**link separately**

http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

**link inline markdown**

[Test link](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

**link using link button in editor**

[Test link][1]


  [1]: http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans
```